# What is a binfilter?

Tags: download, openoffice, open-source, sdk, source-code

[OpenOffice.org download options](http://download.openoffice.org/other.html) page lists a source archive file named "binfilter".

[image]

**What is a binfilter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the file formats supported, check here for more information about it:
http://framework.openoffice.org/binfilter.html

Is has been obsolete since OOo 1.1 and should be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

From the [framework wiki page](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Modules/binfilter):

> Binary Filters provides the import / export filters for the old StarOffice file formats.

So, in short, it provides the ability to open older binary StarOffice file formats which are now obsolete.